# How to name an abstract class that all components extend from?

Tags: typescript, naming-conventions, angular5

I have a simple abstract class that have some common properties and methods, that all my components want to share. This abstract class in not a component by itself but all my components extend it. My naming convention for components is to name for example `SidePanelComponent` class at a file `sidePanel.component.ts`. The question is, what is the recommended convention to name my Base Abstract class?

```
abstract class Base {}
```

or

```
abstract class BaseComponent {}


@Component({
   ....
})
class SidePanelComponent extends Base {}
```

Should I name my Base class using the component keyword in the name even though it is not a component by itself?

Answer (score 0):

`BaseComponent`. `Base` is way too board and does not tell what it does.

Think about if you have another set of abstraction, will you name it `Base` again?

For `Component`, maybe it's ok to use abstract class.
But always consider composition and other means before relying on inheritance. Inheritance is a strong coupling mechanism.

It would well worth your time to doublethink would those properties and methods come from a different set of concerns.